# Convert packed decimal to decimal in AB initio

Tags: data-warehouse, ab-initio

I am having my source data dml as **packed decimal data type** and i want to reformat it as only decimal data type.

eg.

```
original DML :-   packed decimal(5,2) Salary   
Reformated DML:-  decimal(",") salary

packed decimal(5,2) Salary  => decimal(",") salary
```

How can i type cast this packed decimal with decimal in AB initio ?

Answer (score 0):

Ab Initio DML automatically casts between compatible types. So simply map the packed decimal "Salary" onto the regular decimal "salary" in a transform component and the casting will just happen. That being said, you should feel free to direct these questions to support@abinitio.com. They're always happy to help.